# Android toolbar is sizing incorrectly when I try to set translucency

Tags: android, android-toolbar

I'm trying to set my app up so I have a translucent status and navigation bar.

At first I was having a problem where the status bar would overlap my toolbar.  when I had android:fitsSystemWindows="false" in the top level.  I found a post that someone said I should put android:fitsSystemWindows="true" not in the top level, but second level so it would fill the window, but not overlap the status bar.

I put it into the toolbar, and now I'm getting the following

https://i.stack.imgur.com/M7txG.jpg

I also tried wrapping the entire layout with another LinearLayout that then had the flag, but it turns the translucency off?

It's happening on both kitkat and lollipop. I'm lost as to what is happening..

Edit: If I turn translucent navigation bars to false, the toolbar is correct, but I lose the translucent navigation bars.

This is my layout

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/orange"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/background_material_light"
        tools:context=".HomeActivity">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/content_frame"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
            android:layout_width="260dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:background="@color/background_material_light" />

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

My Theme

```
<style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
</style>
```

Comment: try instead of height:wrap_content use android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"

Comment: When I try that, it shrinks it to the size of an actionbar, being overlapped by the status bar, with no actionbar content being shown.  It's just an orange bar, with the status bar over it.

Comment: I think you have to set `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` for the top layout container as well.

Comment: `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` in the top level is actually disabling transparency.  My original post had an error, I must have had it in the top level set to false, and that's when it causes the status bar overlap.

This is what it looks like if i put false up top - http://imgur.com/2VepEWL

Comment: I just tried wrapping only the toolbar with a wrap_content linearlayout with the flag set to true, and this is what happened - http://imgur.com/f1qj4kY

Comment: Had to deal with the same type of UI, here's what I did:
`<Drawer>
  <LinearLayout> <Toolbar/> <FrameLayout/> </LinearLayout>
  <Menu/>
</Drawer>`.
`Menu` and `Toolbar` have a top padding of 25dp for v21, and 0dp otherwise. No `fitsSystemWindows` anywhere.

Comment: I tried this, and it can work, but I'm concerned about hard coding the value. The translucency on the navigation bar isn't critical, and I think I'd rather leave it off and ensure I won't run into problems.